# How to pass simple array to ajax request?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I've got the following code:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var ris = new Array();
      for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        ris[j] = [($("[name=ris" + j + "]").val())];
      $.ajax({
        url: "crea_sondaggio.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          ris: ris
        }),
      });
    });
```

with this array:

```
var ris = new Array();
      for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        ris[j] = [($("[name=ris" + j + "]").val())];
```

and I want to send it to Ajax. Is it right:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
      ris: ris
    }),
```

How can I fix?

**UPDATE**

**js/php**

```
<form action="crea_sondaggio.php" method="post">
     ...other code here....
</form>
$("form").submit(function(e) {
                var ris = new Array();
                for (var j=0; j<=i; j++) 
                    ris[j] = [($("[name=ris"+j+"]").val())];
                $.ajax({
                    url: "crea_sondaggio.php",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: {ris: JSON.stringify(ris)},
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function() {
                        alert("OK");
                    },
                    error: function(err, msg) {
                        alert ("Chiamata fallita " + msg);
                    }
                });
            });
```

**crea_sondaggio.php**

```
$ris = $_POST['ris'];
echo $ris;
```

But page crea_sondaggio.php is empty and it doesn't appear the output $ris. How can I fix?

Comment: So what's wrong? You can stringify array and send it using ajax...

Comment: You are getting values from input type='text'?

Comment: Both ways are correct. Would be even better if you set the correct content-type. In the first case you are incorrectly accessing the data in php.

Comment: So what Do I have to write in the code, please?

Comment: that info is available online. here on SO even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save all the values of input textboxes in array please use below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ris = new Array();
    $("input[name^='ris']").each(function() {
        ris.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

JSON.stringify for array and pass that in the request parameter.

```
data: {
  ris: JSON.stringify(ris)
},
```

Comment: It doesn't work. In my php code I've written `$ris = $_POST['ris']; echo $ris;` but the page is empty.

Comment: After push values in ris array can you please check console.log(ris) before ajax call.

Comment: I re-write my code and now it works because it makes alert OK for the success function in ajax. But It doesn't take the value of ris in php page. How can I fix?

Comment: Can you please print entire $_POST array in PHP and check what you are getting in it?  By print_r($_POST)

Comment: I updated the question adding other code